# 'class': type parameter 'param' is incompatible with the declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This code compiles successfully with Visual Studio 2015, but in Visual Studio 2019 I receive the following error:

> 'std::lock_guard': template parameter '_Mutex' is incompatible with the declaration

Line with error:

```cpp
template<class... mutex_types> friend class std::lock_guard;  // C++17 or MSVS2015
```

safe_ptr.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef SAFE_PTR_H
#define SAFE_PTR_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <new>
//#include <shared_mutex>

template<typename T, typename mutex_t = std::recursive_mutex, typename x_lock_t = std::unique_lock<mutex_t>,
    typename s_lock_t = std::unique_lock<mutex_t >>
    // std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex>, when mutex_t = std::shared_timed_mutex
class safe_ptr {
    typedef mutex_t mtx_t;
    const std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
    std::shared_ptr<mutex_t> mtx_ptr;

    template<typename req_lock>
    class auto_lock_t {
        T * const ptr;
        req_lock lock;
    public:
        auto_lock_t(auto_lock_t&& o) : ptr(std::move(o.ptr)), lock(std::move(o.lock)) { }
        auto_lock_t(T * const _ptr, mutex_t& _mtx) : ptr(_ptr), lock(_mtx){}
        T* operator -> () { return ptr; }
        const T* operator -> () const { return ptr; }
    };

    template<typename req_lock>
    class auto_lock_obj_t {
        T * const ptr;
        req_lock lock;
    public:
        auto_lock_obj_t(auto_lock_obj_t&& o) : ptr(std::move(o.ptr)), lock(std::move(o.lock)) { }
        auto_lock_obj_t(T * const _ptr, mutex_t& _mtx) : ptr(_ptr), lock(_mtx){}
        template<typename arg_t>
        auto operator [] (arg_t arg) -> decltype((*ptr)[arg]) { return (*ptr)[arg]; }
    };

    void lock() { mtx_ptr->lock(); }
    void unlock() { mtx_ptr->unlock(); }
    friend struct link_safe_ptrs;
    template<size_t, typename, size_t, size_t> friend class lock_timed_any;
#if (_WIN32 && _MSC_VER < 1900)
    template<class mutex_type> friend class std::lock_guard;  // MSVS2013 or Clang 4.0
#else
  // The error is on the next line
    template<class... mutex_types> friend class std::lock_guard;  // C++17 or MSVS2015
#endif
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    safe_ptr(Args... args) : ptr(std::make_shared<T>(args...)), mtx_ptr(std::make_shared<mutex_t>()) {}

    auto_lock_t<x_lock_t> operator -> () { return auto_lock_t<x_lock_t>(ptr.get(), *mtx_ptr); }
    auto_lock_obj_t<x_lock_t> operator * () { return auto_lock_obj_t<x_lock_t>(ptr.get(), *mtx_ptr); }
    const auto_lock_t<s_lock_t> operator -> () const { return auto_lock_t<s_lock_t>(ptr.get(), *mtx_ptr); }
    const auto_lock_obj_t<s_lock_t> operator * () const { return auto_lock_obj_t<s_lock_t>(ptr.get(), *mtx_ptr); }
};
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

struct link_safe_ptrs {
    template<typename T1, typename... Args>
    link_safe_ptrs(T1 &first_ptr, Args&... args) {
        std::lock_guard<T1> lock(first_ptr);
        typedef typename T1::mtx_t mutex_t;
        std::shared_ptr<mutex_t> old_mtxs[] = { args.mtx_ptr ... }; // to unlock before mutexes destroyed
        std::shared_ptr<std::lock_guard<mutex_t>> locks[] = { std::make_shared<std::lock_guard<mutex_t>>(*args.mtx_ptr) ... };
        std::shared_ptr<mutex_t> mtxs[] = { args.mtx_ptr = first_ptr.mtx_ptr ... };
    }
};
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

enum lock_count_t { lock_once, lock_infinity };

template<size_t lock_count, typename duration = std::chrono::nanoseconds,
    size_t deadlock_timeout = 100000, size_t spin_iterations = 100>
class lock_timed_any {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<void>> locks_ptr_vec;
    bool success;

    template<typename mtx_t>
    std::unique_lock<mtx_t> try_lock_one(mtx_t &mtx) const {
        std::unique_lock<mtx_t> lock(mtx, std::defer_lock_t());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < spin_iterations; ++i) if (lock.try_lock()) return lock;
        const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        //while (!lock.try_lock_for(duration(deadlock_timeout)))    // only for timed mutexes
        while (!lock.try_lock()) {
            auto const time_remained = duration(deadlock_timeout) - std::chrono::duration_cast<duration>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start_time);
            if (time_remained <= duration(0))
                break;
            else 
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(time_remained);
        }
        return lock;
    }

    template<typename mtx_t>
    std::shared_ptr<std::unique_lock<mtx_t>> try_lock_ptr_one(mtx_t &mtx) const {
        return std::make_shared<std::unique_lock<mtx_t>>(try_lock_one(mtx));
    }

public:
    template<typename... Args>
    lock_timed_any(Args& ...args) {
        do {
            success = true;
            for (auto &lock_ptr : { try_lock_ptr_one(*args.mtx_ptr.get()) ... }) {
                locks_ptr_vec.emplace_back(lock_ptr);
                if (!lock_ptr->owns_lock()) {
                    success = false;
                    locks_ptr_vec.clear();
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration(deadlock_timeout));
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (!success && lock_count == lock_count_t::lock_infinity);
    }

    explicit operator bool() const throw() { return success; }
    lock_timed_any(lock_timed_any&& other) throw() : locks_ptr_vec(other.locks_ptr_vec) { }
    lock_timed_any(const lock_timed_any&) = delete;
    lock_timed_any& operator=(const lock_timed_any&) = delete;
};

using lock_timed_any_once = lock_timed_any<lock_count_t::lock_once>;
using lock_timed_any_infinity = lock_timed_any<lock_count_t::lock_infinity>;
// ---------------------------------------------------------------


#endif // #ifndef SAFE_PTR_H
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include "safe_ptr.h"

struct user_accounts_t { 
    std::string user_name; int64_t money; 
    user_accounts_t(std::string u, int64_t m) : user_name(u), money(m) {}
};

safe_ptr<std::map<uint64_t, user_accounts_t >> safe_user_accounts(
    std::map<uint64_t, user_accounts_t >({
    std::make_pair(1, user_accounts_t("John Smith", 100)),
    std::make_pair(2, user_accounts_t("John Rambo", 150))
}));

struct cash_flows_t { uint64_t unique_id, src_id, dst_id, time; int64_t money; };

std::atomic<uint64_t> global_unique_id;
safe_ptr<std::multimap<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<cash_flows_t>>> safe_cash_flows_src_id;
safe_ptr<std::multimap<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<cash_flows_t>>> safe_cash_flows_dst_id;

// too much granularity (very slow) 
//static link_safe_ptrs tmp_link(safe_user_accounts, safe_cash_flows_src_id, safe_cash_flows_dst_id); 


void move_money(uint64_t src_id, uint64_t dst_id, uint64_t time, int64_t money)
{
    auto cash_flow_row_ptr = std::make_shared<cash_flows_t>();
    cash_flow_row_ptr->unique_id = ++global_unique_id;
    cash_flow_row_ptr->src_id = src_id;
    cash_flow_row_ptr->dst_id = dst_id;
    cash_flow_row_ptr->time = time;
    cash_flow_row_ptr->money = money;

    std::cout << " - start transaction... move_money() \n";
    lock_timed_any_infinity lock_all(safe_cash_flows_src_id, safe_cash_flows_dst_id, safe_user_accounts);   // 2, 3, 1

    // update table-1
    safe_user_accounts->at(src_id).money -= money;            
    safe_user_accounts->at(dst_id).money += money;

    // inset to indexes in table safe_cash_flows: src & dst
    safe_cash_flows_src_id->emplace(src_id, cash_flow_row_ptr);
    safe_cash_flows_dst_id->emplace(dst_id, cash_flow_row_ptr);

    std::cout << " - end transaction: move_money() \n";
}

void show_total_amount() 
{
        int64_t total_amount = 0;

        std::cout << " - start transaction... show_total_amount() \n";
        lock_timed_any_infinity lock_all(safe_user_accounts);            // 1

        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (auto it = safe_user_accounts->begin(); it != safe_user_accounts->end(); ++it) {
            total_amount += it->second.money;
            std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second.user_name << ", " <<
                it->second.money << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Result: all accounts total_amount = " << total_amount << " \t <<< \n\n";

        std::cout << " - end transaction: show_total_amount() \n";
}


void show_user_money_on_time(uint64_t user_id, uint64_t time)
{
        int64_t incoming = 0;
        int64_t outcoming = 0;
        int64_t user_money = 0;
        std::string user_name;

        std::cout << " - start transaction... show_user_money_on_time() \n";
        lock_timed_any_infinity lock_all(safe_cash_flows_dst_id, safe_cash_flows_src_id, safe_user_accounts);     // 3, 2, 1   

        std::cout << std::endl;
        auto in_range = safe_cash_flows_dst_id->equal_range(user_id);
        for (auto it = in_range.first; it != in_range.second; ++it)
            if (it->second->time > time)
                incoming += it->second->money;

        auto out_range = safe_cash_flows_src_id->equal_range(user_id);
        for (auto it = out_range.first; it != out_range.second; ++it)
            if (it->second->time > time)
                outcoming += it->second->money;

        user_money = safe_user_accounts->at(user_id).money;
        user_name = safe_user_accounts->at(user_id).user_name;

        std::cout << std::endl << "incoming = " << incoming << ", outcoming = " << outcoming <<
            ", current user_money = " << user_money << std::endl;

        user_money = user_money - incoming + outcoming; // take into account cash flow

        std::cout << user_id << " => " << user_name << ", " << user_money <<
            ", at time = " << time << " \t <<< \n\n";

        std::cout << " - end transaction: show_user_money_on_time() \n";
}

int main() {

    std::cout << "Init table safe_user_accounts: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "at time = 0  \t\t <<< " << std::endl;

    for (auto it = safe_user_accounts->begin(); it != safe_user_accounts->end(); ++it)
        std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second.user_name << ", " <<
        it->second.money << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::thread t1([&]() { move_money(2, 1, 12, 50); });    // src_id, dst_id, time, money

    std::thread t2([&]() { show_total_amount(); });

    std::thread t3([&]() { show_user_money_on_time(1, 0); });   // user_id, time

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    std::cout << "end";
    int b; std::cin >> b;

    return 0;
}
```

Original author's [repository](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/object_threadsafe/tree/master/any_object_threadsafe).

Comment: We need to see an [mre] with enough code that we can reproduce your problem _within the question_.  [Edit] your question to include enough code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Far too much code.

Comment: Please give credit for [code that you did not write](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/object_threadsafe/blob/master/any_object_threadsafe/safe_ptr.h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in MSVS 2015 (**1900**) where it is implemented as

`template<class... _Mutexes> class lock_guard`

So such macro can be used to fix this bug in MSVS 1900.

All other compilers use correct implementation `template<class _Mutex> class lock_guard`

---

Initially in the C++17 there was proposed lock_guard for multiple mutexes (Variadic lock_guard) `template <typename ...MutexTypes> class lock_guard` for C++17: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4470.html

But later lock_guard for multiple mutexes (Variadic lock_guard) was replaced by scoped_lock for multiple mutexes (Variadic scoped_lock) `template <class... MutexTypes> class scoped_lock;`: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0156r2.html

It seems that in MSVS 2015 was implemented first C++17 draft with Variadic lock_guard, but later C++17 was released with Variadic scoped_lock: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock

---

**MSVS 2013 (1800)**

[image]

---

**MSVS 2015 (1900)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is exactly what I wanted to know. I noticed that you are interested in multithreading, could you tell me how I should do: I work with one object (which is in a std::map) in several threads, what do I need to use, a thread-safe object or a thread-safe container?
Thanks again.

Comment: @chaot1c You should use thread-safe object (if you don't delete this objects from map and don't change its key)

Answer (score 1):

`std::lock_guard` is a template with exactly one template parameter, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard

`template<class... mutex_types>` means you are refering to a declaration with zero or multiple template parameters, which leads to the error message "is incompatible with the declaration".

A minimal example of this issue :

```
template <typename X> class Bar {};
template <typename... Xs> class Foo {};

class Baz {
    template<class> friend class Bar;
    template<class...> friend class Foo;
};
```

Comment: Yeah I don't know what that OS/implementation switching is for.

Comment: I've put a comment on the relevant commit into the original author's GitHub repo.